# Ruby regex match then exclude from match

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a URL like so:

```
http://www.example.com/blah.ashx?ID=fj203-fj230r-3jf030
```

I was wondering if it's possible to match everything from the ID= to the end of the URL in Ruby, then exclude the ID= from the match? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is. Please post what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

```
"http://www.example.com/blah.ashx?ID=fj203-fj230r-3jf030"[/(?<=ID=)(.*)/]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby probably has a built in URL and query-string parser, but this regex should work simply enough:

```
\?ID=(.*)
```

http://rubular.com/r/kYf3EURRPN

Answer (score 2):

I always stick with library methods, lets me sleep better ;-)

```
require 'cgi'
require 'uri'

uri    = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/blah.ashx?ID=fj203-fj230r-3jf030')
params = CGI.parse(uri.query)
id     = params["ID"].first

#=> "fj203-fj230r-3jf030"
```